# jQuery .click() not functioning

Tags: jquery, click

I have built a `<ul>` list and it is being populated with `<li id="subsitem">` from a jQuery function. I am trying to build a click function so that whenever one of those `<li>`'s is clicked, it disappears. I'm using the `slideUp()` function.

Here is my code:

```
$("#subsitem").click(function() {
  // Act on the event
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

This doesn't work, yet when i change it to

```
$("li").click(function() {
  // Act on the event
  $(this).slideUp();
});
```

It works, but the only problem then is it works on all my `<li>`s. Anyone any tips?

---

### update

Here is the code that is being used inside an .each()

```
$("#subs").append("<li><a href='#' class='subsitem'><div class='favicon'><img src='icon.png' width='16' height='16'></div>title</a></li>");
```

Comment: Please show some HTML, and the jQuery code that does the populating.

Comment: +1 @Ken. We cant help if we cant see the HTML

Comment: You shouldn't place a `<div>` inside an `<a>`. As inline elements, `<a>` tags should only contain other inline elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok having used the jquery irc channel i managed to get the answer i was looking for.

I needed to use the .live() function.  This is what my code now looks like

```
$("#subsitem").live('click',function(){
$(this).parent().slideUp();});
```

Comment: Upon investigation, that is exactly what you needed to do :) Thanks for the update, can you accept your own answer?

Comment: Yea I will do, once it allows me

Answer (score 4):

The problem is the first one is identifying by ID, which should be unique. You can change it to a class, and add the class to each li, to make it work.

```
$(".subitem").click(function() {
    // Act on the event
    $(this).slideUp();
});
```

Comment: i know the code works, because if i create another list on the same page with the li and class, then the code works fine, its almost like my first ul list is bugged

Comment: You need to append `$("#subs").append("<li class='subitem'><a href='#' class='subsitem'><div class='favicon'><img src='icon.png' width='16' height='16'></div>title</a></li>");` for my code to work. The difference being the `<li>` having subitem as the class.

Answer (score 1):

What about doing something like:

```
$("#subsitem").click(function(){
    $(this).parent().slideUp();
});
```

To bind it to the parent `<li>` of the `<a>` that is clicked.